# DOMDocument::createElementNS():

Tags: php

I am getting this error

DOMDocument::createElementNS(): unterminated entity reference            aV5W

when I try to perform the SOAP call to get the VersionInfo. I am suspecting that I have a "&" in my password. I am using the PHP Kit provided at:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api/connecting_to_the_api_using_php/

May I know what could be the exact problem?

Thanks,
Adam

Comment: Can you confirm that changing your password so that it is just alphanumeric fixes the problem?